# Migrating from mvc4 to mvc5, attribute routing do not work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a asp.net mvc4/webapi using SimpleMembershipProvider that I'm trying to update to mvc5/webapi2 with the new asp.net Identity. I updated all assemblies, remove the obsolete ones, deleted my old AuthController and created a new, based on the basic mvc5 app from vs2013. Corrected all errors and changed a little my javascript to point to the new controller. I do not need to migrate users, so just dropped the database and let it create a new one. All is working fine except for one detail:

```
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:12128/api/Account/Register'.
```

If I remove the `[Route("Register")]` from the `Register` method, it works. But I want to use atribute routing...  so I think my question is, what exactly enables attribute routing on mvc 5? Maybe I am forgeting something on web.config, or to call some method or even some old assembly still on the project... but I cannot find any difference betwen my app and the basic app. Any hint would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling `MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` extension on `HttpConfiguration`? Note that traditional routing can never access controller/actions decorated with attribute routes. You would have to explicitly remove the attribute routing specific attributes from all controllers/actions if you would want them to be accessible by traditional routes.

Also you may need to make additional changes to your MVC4 app to upgrade to MVC5. Following blog post can help you:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

Comment: Thanks for you answer Kiran. I am calling `MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` (and the code is being executed) and already did all the instructions on the blog post you suggested. If on my `AccountController` I create a method `Test`, it works until I put [Route("Test")] there. So, it seems that my app is not picking up the attributes but are changing something on the routes when I use them... I will try to remove all code from my app and create a minimal sample that still reproduces this behaviour to see if there is something else causing this.

Comment: Hmm, could you share how your controller and actions look like? and also how your request looks like?

Comment: I ended up finding another file defining a global route that was being executed before the `MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` call. I changed the call order and all is working now. Thanks!